# Programming a Discord bot in Python- How do I make the bot repeat an image?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make my bot repeat the image someone sends (when a specific phrase is mentioned). Here's my code:

```
submission_triggers = ['#submission', '#Submission']

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
   return
  
  if any(word in msg for word in submission_triggers):
    channel = client.get_channel(800476409587171369)
    image = message.content
    channel.send(file=discord.File(image))
```

This code does not work, I get this error:
`No such file or directory: '#submission'`
Not quite sure how to fix this. I'm new to programming, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: case-sensitivity issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.attachment` attribute of message object to get access to the attachments provided. You can then get access to the `.url` attribute and send that.

You also missed an `await` on the `channel.send()`

```
submission_triggers = ['#submission', '#Submission']

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
   return
  
  if any(word in msg for word in submission_triggers):
    channel = client.get_channel(800476409587171369)
    image_url = message.attachments[0].url # Attachments are stored in a list, so get the first one.
    await channel.send("{url}")
```

Btw, you can get rid of the submission triggers list by changing your if statement:

```
if "#submission" in msg.lower().split():
```

Answer (score 1):

`message.content` also contains the text portion of the message, `#submission`. Preprocess `message.content` to exclude the text portion in order to eliminate the error.